# How to connect UIPopoverViewController in StoryBoard

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I am trying to implement `UIPopoverController`. I have seen some sample code but still confused on how to connect the popover view controller to storyboard. Help please.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!patientPopover) {
      UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryboard" bundle:nil];
      MyViewController * addPacientController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];
      UINavigationController * myNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:MyViewController];
      patientPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:myNavController];
      patientPopover.delegate = self; // optional
}
[patientPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:yourInstanceBarButtonItemOrMethodArgumentAttachedToTheBarButtonItem permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

It's good to have your popover in an instance variable so that you avoid allocating it each time you press the button. I am using here presenting the popover from a `UIBarButtonItem`, but you can also present it from any view, like :

```
[patientPopover presentPopoverFromRect:yourView.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

You don't need to visually see the actual popover in the storyboard or nib file, because it is only a container. You just need to see what goes inside it, and that is the view controller, and obviously, you can do that.

Comment: How to add images and text into this.I'm new to this. Also is there any way we can physically see this in storyboard

Comment: no, there is not. Just type popover on bottom search bar for the UI objects in the utilities window. But you don't need to see it, because the popover is only a container. you only need to see the view controller, or the navigation controller, or the tab bar controller (whichever contains your view controller - or not), and you obviously can do that.